# Switch Statement constant issue

Tags: objective-c, c, constants, switch-statement

```
- (void)change:(int)a {
   int number = a;
   int max = 10;

   switch(max) {
     case number:
       //Do something
       break;

       //.... more cases
   }
}
```

This is just a small example of the issue I can't seem to solve. I have looked at similar posts and answers usually include using constants via a #define or enum, however these are great when you have a constant that is fixed but if the value is passed through as a parameter how could I do this? if it's possible at all. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to use a switch for this? if conditional would be better suited to the job

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish by using a switch statement rather than an if statement?  I do not understand your example which I assume was kind of made up.  Can you provide a more realistic example of what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, `case` statements can only operate on constant expressions, so if you need more dynamic conditionals, you will have to use `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement is used to test the value of a variable against a list of constant expressions.  The difference between a switch with its various case statements and a series of if/elseif statements for the same comparisons is more of a syntax difference than a logic difference.

However the if/elseif statements are more flexible since they do not require constant expressions and you can also use more complex logical expressions in the if/elseif as well.

For instance:

```
switch (iValue) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

has the same meaning as this series of if/elseif statements:

```
if (iValue == 1) {
} else if (iValue == 4) {
} else {
}
```

Most of the time a compiler will generate a series of if/elseif code when it is generating the code for a switch statement.  So the actual code generated by the compiler for an if/elseif statement series is similar to the code generated for a switch statement.